# How to add quicklinks/shortcuts for directories in powershell?

Tags: powershell, wd

I'm looking for a functionality similar to [wd](https://github.com/mfaerevaag/wd) with ZSH where you can add a "warp point" A and then use `wd A` to change to that directory. I searched for something like this but I wasn't successful. Maybe, I didn't use the proper key words..

Any idea of a plugin that provides similar functionality in powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest matches to this feature are listed in the post
[Create a folder alias in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597839/create-a-folder-alias-in-powershell) :

**Turn a folder into a new PowerShell drive with
[New-PSDrive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx) :**

> ```
> New-PSDrive foo filesystem 'C:\Program Files'
> New-PSDrive bar filesystem 'foo:\Microsoft'
> cd foo:
> ```
>
> To persist between sessions you could add them to your profile script
> ($profile).
>
> But of course you can also cd to a folder from a variable
>
> ```
> $foo = 'C:\Program Files'
> $bar = Join-Path $foo 'Microsoft'
> cd $foo
> ```

**Write a function that `cd`'s to that directory**

For instance, put the following function in `profile.ps1`:

```
# quickly cd to folder
function <short name> {
    cd <path to directory>
}
```

Then, in PowerShell:

```
PS> <short name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simulate such functionality with a global `HashTable`. Example:

```
$mdirs = @{
  git = "D:\Something\git"
  docs = "C:\Users\Bob\Documents"
  art = "F:\Art"
}
```

Call e.g. `$mdirs.git` to get the value. This has an advantage of you being able to call `$mdirs` to see all the definitions, there's also <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion.

For it to be global/permament, you need to add it to your profile, which is required also by pretty much all other solutions. You can enter `$PROFILE` in your PowerShell console(s) to know where their profile files reside, it differs per version.

The disadvantage is that you need to edit the file for any future changes. A fully dynamic solution wouldn't be too hard to code though. You could just write few functions that add/read/remove unique aliases to/from a file and then in profile use the read function to set up either a `HashTable` or anything else.